# How do I "install" specific web files on a proxy server?

Tags: html, proxy, webserver

This is for a in house system, that is required to be set-up this way.

I need specific web files, for example, all images to be **manually pre-installed** on a proxy server and never downloaded from the web server.

When the browser request the page, the only thing sent from the web server to the proxy should be the plain html page.

I would then like the images the html page uses, to be grabbed from the the proxy every time, for the complete render to the browser.

Is there a name for this set up? I have seen about caching but I do not even want the images downladed once. In addition, how would the html page know to use the images from the proxy?

How would I set up such a thing? I do not have a proxy server set-up yet so I do not know what platform I will be using, but suggestions are appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Wouldn't setting up a real webserver work, too?

Comment: "never" could be a very looooong time

Comment: I hear you, it is a requirement for this project.

Comment: Why not just set up your proxy server to act concurrently as a Web server for static elements like images, audio, etc.?

Comment: Setting the proxy to act concurrently as a Web server for static elements would achieve this behavior? It would not request images from the main server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think that you could, for example, use [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) and tell it to redirect some queries for images to a local server or even let it replace the `img src="` attribute inline using regexes.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Would the main web server have any problems with not having the image on its server?

Comment: @Tommy: No, if privoxy redirects a request, the actual server can't see the original one.